# Delete Exchange 2003 Emails with WebDav

Tags: exchange-server, webdav

I am trying to manage an Inbox in Exchange 2003 automatically using webdav from a C# application.  Looking at msdn is not helping me a whole lot as the methods described here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142917.aspx) do not coincide at all with the samples I have found otherwise.  So there are two things I am trying to determine:

Of all the fields that return from a webdav query

```
string reqStr =
                @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                <g:searchrequest xmlns:g=""DAV:"">
                    <g:sql>
                        SELECT
                            *
                        FROM
                            ""http://server/Exchange/email1@domain.com/Inbox/""
                        WHERE ""urn:schemas:mailheader:from"" = 'email2@domain.com'
                        </g:sql>
                </g:searchrequest>";
```

Which one is the unique identifier?  I have browsed it (but not sure of a reference to verify the fields) and it appears at first glance that DAV:id is what I want (), but I am not wanting to work on assumptions.

Secondly, what is the correct way to programmatically delete an email after I have processed it?  Would something like the following work (will it remove the entry and all related metadata).  I don't want any files left orphaned on the server...

```
string reqStr =
                @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                <g:searchrequest xmlns:g=""DAV:"">
                    <g:sql>
                        DELETE
                        FROM
                            ""http://server/Exchange/email1@domain.com/Inbox/""
                        WHERE ""DAV:id"" = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'                                                       
                        </g:sql>
                </g:searchrequest>";
```

And finally, what are the best online sources for investigating all the data returned in the XML from the first request, and where are all the options documented for managing the webdav interface?  Looking at MSDN just hasn't been fruitful.

Comment: Well, I have determined this absolutely will not work, I get a 400 Bad Request back from the server.  I'm still in need of a way to delete individual emails.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142839(v=EXCHG.65).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the dav:hef tags tag in the response. They contain an url you can use to issue a delete command.

Comment: Ok, I see this <a:href> with a URL.  How would I formulate a DELETE?  Would it be the same as above, except the WHERE clause is for ""DAV:ID"" = 'urlstring'

Comment: I guess as a follow up, do I need to do anything to clean up the nodes where <a:propstat><a:status> = 404?  It seems there is a 404 for every 200.

Comment: You just issue a HTTP DELETE command to the url. Nothing more. You get the 404 errors for properties which do not exist. Just ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

From the result of a query that gets you the msg Uri then:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(mail.MailUri);
request.Credentials = _credential;
request.Method = "DELETE";

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
   //something might of broke
}
```